# Can I configure a TLD in a DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm pretty new to DNS. From what I've learnt so far, I know that: when a DNS server is asked to resolve some domain name (assuming all caches are empty), it will first contact a root name server, and ask for the name sever of the TLD, and keep asking his way to the authoritative name server of the domain name in question.

My question is, say I have a company with a local network with a bunch of machines, printers and services etc. Can I have a domain name for my internal network so that each machine and service will have a domain name? I know that it's possible, my question is more how is it possible? Since it seems that when a DNS server is asked for a domain name it goes from top (root servers) to bottom, so how can I have a domain name that is not part of this public hierarchy?

Comment: The `.local` domain is common for this purpose. The clients use the system configured DNS, if you control that server you can inject anything you want.

Comment: Do _not_ use the `.local` TLD for that purpose. It is reserved for mDNS. Using it as a regular local zone can cause malfunctions which may be quite difficult to resolve.

Comment: "Can I have a domain name for my internal network so that each machine and service will have a domain name?" Just register any domain publicly (in any TLD you like) and then use it as suffix for any internal name. DO NOT invent new TLDs internally. And of course DO NOT hijack existing ones either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is that when a DNS server is queried for a domain name it does not necessarily start with the official root servers. There are exceptions to that rule which offer you the opportunity to insert your own domain.

Generally speaking, when the DNS server already knows the answer for a query then it uses that answer instead of going through the complete drill starting at the root servers. This applies on all levels. So when a DNS server is asked for `somehost.subdom.example.com` and it already knows the NS record for `example.com`, it will start with that knowledge and proceed from there directly to `subdom.example.com` instead of unnecessarily asking the root servers for the NS record for `com` again. Possible sources for that knowledge include the cache of recent queries but also the DNS zones which are configured locally on the server.

Consequently, if you configure a zone `example.com` on your DNS server then every query for a domain name below `example.com` going through that server will effectively be served from that zone, masking out any results for the same query from the public DNS hierarchy. You'll have created your own private version of that domain. Note that any query *not* going through your DNS server will still return the results from the public DNS hierarchy, so you'll want to make sure that all DNS queries from your company network go (directly or indirectly) to your DNS server which has that extra zone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Totally trivial to do. Technically it is not a TLD, though - the TLD is ".", you are the first tier domain.

Obviously, as you are not delegated, well, no one else will get the information unless he uses your dns server(s).

Not a lot of experience, right? Because this is EXACTLY how i.e. Active Directory manages a domain. Set up their own domain, all domain members use (must use) the active directory DNS Servers).

Comment: "the TLD is ".", ". No. By definition, "." is root, and TLD aka Top Level Domain is the first label beneath it.